# AWS S3 and Route 53: www redirect does not work

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-route53, aws-directory-service

I have hosted my static website on AWS S3, like in,

http://example.net

I have configured two S3 buckets, one for http://example.net, and another
one for http://www.example.net, whose 'Static web hosting' has been setup
to redirect to http://example.net.

Since my domain name was bought with some other provider, I have added Hosted
Zones on Route 53 for both the entries. I have also configured record sets
for both the entries.  The record sets of http://www.example.net have the
same contents as http://example.net

While http://example.net is working (I am able to browse as well as ping
this domain, I am not able to ping as well as browse to http://www.example.net.
Ping fails with the following error:

"Ping request could not find host www.example.net. Please check the name and try again."

Any help or information to resolve this issue would be much appreciated.

Note: All references to 'example.net' is just an example, and the real name
of my domain name is different.

Comment: It may be much easier if you gave us the real domain name. Then we could have a look what's wrong with it. After all it's a public website, no need to keep its name secret.

Comment: @MLu: Thank you so much for your response. I have provided the domain name through LinkedIn. Request to connect there. Thank you for your understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Your DNS for the *real domain that you shared with me* seems incompletely configured.

This is the "`example.net`" record:

```
$ dig a example.net
example.net.        5   IN  A   52.219.xx.xx
```

While this is the "`www.example.net`" record:

```
$ dig a www.example.net
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 21945
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www.example.net.           IN  A
```

Apparently the record for `www` doesn't exist. Re-check your Route53 settings.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Here is my Route 53 configuration for www.example.net :

A: Alias Target: s3-website.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com.

NS: ns-799.awsdns-35.net. 
ns-1803.awsdns-33.co.uk. 
ns-1477.awsdns-56.org. 
ns-80.awsdns-10.com.

SOA: ns-1803.awsdns-33.co.uk. awsdns-hostmaster.amazon.com. 1 7200 900 1209600 86400


Am I missing anything? Thanks.

Comment: @VenkatRamakrishnan Your `A ALIAS` target for the `www` may have a typo or invalid bucket name or something like that. It doesn't resolve to an IP address.

Comment: I did a 'Test Record Set' on www.example.net Route 53 record, it does return a valid IP address. The DNS Response Code also shows 'NOERROR'. So, why does it work internally on Route 53, whereas not getting propagated to the DNS?